# Differentiating between an integer and a special character in switch() function

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with a program that is supposed to read a number or a special character from standard input and depending on what it reads, run a specific function. If the input is a number it should be put on a stack and if its a special character it should trigger one of math functions. However I can't figure which input function or trick should I use. I created a switch() function

```
scanf("%c", a);
 switch(a) { 
  case'+':
   add(stack); 
   break; 
  case '-':
   sub(stack); 
   break;
  case 'number':
   push(stack, a); 
   break;
    ...}
```

However if I use scanf to read an character I have problems with putting it on a stack as a number (atoi() needs a pointer) and if I scanf for integer it can't be compared to characters. Is there any other way to make this work? I tried with multiple scanf's but then I still had problem with differentiating between a number and a special character and ended up with characters being put on the stack.

Comment: Are the numbers in question a single digit or multiple digits?

Comment: Both. Im trying to make it work for both single digits and bigger numbers.

Comment: @dbush: How would you fit multiple digits into a `char`?

Comment: @MtHowever: Not reading it with `%c` you're not.

Comment: Must you accommodate / must you reject leading whitespace before the character / number?  Is a space character, tab, etc. a possible "special character" that you would want to read and process?

Comment: @ScottHunter You don't.  That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: There are 7"special characters", "?", "&", "%", "*", "/", "+", "-"

Comment: `scanf("%c", a);` and/or `switch(a)` should generate a compiler error/warning.  Fully enable your compiler warnings.  Saves time.

Comment: What is `case 'number'` supposed to do? On the one hand, it does not make a valid value for `switch`. On the other if it was supposed to be `"number"` you cannot use that in a `case` statement.

Comment: @MrHowever you may need to compare the ASCII value is in range of numbers and then set a flag saying number and proceed with it separately

Comment: 'number' just means a case where the variable is an number and I just wrote it to show an idea but Im aware it doesn't work and it's not actually in my program

Comment: It should be `scanf("%c", &a)`. You forgot the `&`.

Comment: To accommodate multi-digit int literals, if the character scanned is a digit (something easy to test for) you can `ungetc` it and then `scanf` and `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `case 'number':` is certainly not what was intended, but it is legal. It's a multi-character constant, and its value is implementation-defined. (Multi-character constants are probably used incorrectly more often than they're used correctly.)

Comment: @chux A bunch of digits

Comment: @KeithThompson might be legal sometimes, but MSVC gives "error C2015: too many characters in constant".

Comment: @WeatherVane: Then I believe MSVC is non-conforming. A warning is appropriate, but `'number'` does not violate any syntax rule or constraint. (It has an implementation-defined value of type `int`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson `case 'numb'` gives no error. This is a 32-bit implementation. So it is not unreasonable for MSVC to object to `'number'`. More generally we all know that "MSVC is non-conforming".

Comment: @KeithThompson if this is "implementation defined" how can you say that is "non-conforming"? The MSVC implementation is quite reasonable.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Because it's only the *value* that's implementation-defined. It still has to have some value within the range of type `int`. I'm not necessarily saying MSVC's behavior is unreasonable, only that it violates the ISO C standard.

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` reads a single character at a time.  So you can't use it to read a number with multiple digits, at least not without keeping track of the last character you read and pushing it onto the last number read.

Assuming each of your tokens must be separated by whitespace, you're better of using the `%s` format specifier to read in a string.  Then you would check the first character of the string to see what kind of token it is.

You can make use of fall-through cases to check if you have a digit.

```
char token[20] = "";
scanf("%s", token);
switch (token[0]) {
  case'+':
    add(stack); 
    break; 
  case '-':
    sub(stack); 
    break;
  case '0':
  case '1':
  case '2':
  case '3':
  case '4':
  case '5':
  case '6':
  case '7':
  case '8':
  case '9':
    push(stack, atoi(token)); 
    break;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well are you OK that your calculator can deal with single digit numbers? However to your question. Use isdigit to test the character for digit and push to stack in this case. Otherwise use a big switch.

```
char a;
sscanf ("%c", a);
if (isdigit (a)) {
    int num = atoi (&a);
    push (stack, num);
}
else
    switch (a) {
    ....
    }
```

Edit: Detecting multi digit numbers is easy too, except reading the input. If you're targeting GNU systems, you can use "%ms" flag, which will allocate needed memory.

```
bool isdigita (const char* s)
{
    char c = *s;
    while (c != '\0') {
        if (!isdigit (c))
            return false;
        c = *s++;
    }
    return true;
}

void test_isdigita ()
{
    assert (isdigita ("42"));
    assert (!isdigita (" 42"));
    assert (!isdigita ("42!!"));
    assert (!isdigita ("4!!1"));
}
```

Comment: Try compiling `char a;
sscanf ("%c", a);`.  At least 2 problems in 2 lines.  `char a;  ... int num = atoi (&a);` is also a problem.  `&a` does not point to a _string_ that converts well.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to multi-digit numbers too

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the *fall-through* feature of `case`.

```
scanf("%c", &a);
 switch(a) { 
  case'+':
   add(stack); 
   break; 
  case '-':
   sub(stack); 
   break;
  case '0':
  case '1':
  case '2':
  case '3':
  case '4':
  case '5':
  case '6':
  case '7':
  case '8':
  case '9':
   push(stack, a); 
   break;
    ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first character -- possibly skipping leading whitespace -- and make a decision based on that.  If it is a digit, proceed to read the rest of the number; otherwise match it against the acceptable special characters.  For example:

```
int ch;

// ...

ch = getch();
switch (ch) {
    case -1:
        // handle error / EOF ...
        break;
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        // read the rest of the digits of the number, if any ...
        // push the assembled number ...
        break;
    case '+':
        // ...
        break;
    // ... more cases ...
    case ' ':
        // do nothing
        break;
    default:
        // handle invalid input ...
        break;
}
```

There are other alternatives, too.